# xlwings working with multiple python files

Tags: xlwings

Is it possible to construct multiple UDF python files and call them into a single excel workbook?
It seems as though when importing the py file into excel it must have the same name as the workbook which limits me to work with one py file.
Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UDF Modules in the config (Ribbon or config file or Excel sheet config) as described here: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#global-settings